# Cycling through CSS animations on scroll or click

Tags: css, animation, css-animations, timing, updating

I'm looking to build something akin to the effect you can see on http://www.meetyourmx.com/ - Specifically I mean how the animations launch on page load then when you scroll, or click through the menu the items are animated in various ways to get you through the site.

How can this one after another effect be accomplished? I'm just using standard CSS3 animations currently. Am I looking at a jQuery/AJAX solution?

Just to clarify I'm trying to recreate the fullheight/no scroll bar synced with the animations.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: using something like http://johnpolacek.github.io/scrollorama/ might be a good start

Comment: I was just looking at the pin-it function in scrollorama, thanks for the tip. Would it be a problem though that I don't actually want any height scrolling, if that makes sense?

Comment: Actually, scrollorama should be able to do everything I need, after a little more thought and searching I now realise that. So thanks for your post.

Comment: Perhaps something like [One Page Scroll](http://www.thepetedesign.com/demos/onepage_scroll_demo.html)?